# Using Mid Function to extract name from large text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, export-to-excel

I am looking for help to extract ‘human’ from the large text below:

(Description=(help(save=human)(name=Randolp.trd.com)(place=JPN))(connecting_place=(city_name=tokyo.trd.com)))

(Description=(helplocation_time(save=human)(name=Randolp.trd.com)(place=JPN))(connecting_place=(city_name=tokyo.trd.com)))

I used the mid function to extract but there are too much variables and scenerios that its difficult to pull the information

Comment: What is your excel version? and does save always follows `=human` ? if so then why dont you try this `=MID(A2,FIND("save=",A2)+5,5)` this will extract the human or am i missing anything here.

Comment: what do you mean by extract? if you want to remove "human" then substitute(). But if you want to check it is there then find().

Comment: `ISNUMBER(FIND("(save=human)",A2))` returns TRUE if found, FALSE if not.

Comment: No save=human will not always be the same case. sometimes it will be different name under save.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your large text is in cell `A1`:

`=MID(A1,SEARCH("save=",A1)+5,SEARCH(")(",A1)-(SEARCH("save=",A1)+5))`

This will use the `save=` part of your text before `human`, and the `)(` part after to print out what's between them.

I've had to assume that the first set of `)(` will come after the desired text, otherwise you'll probably have to start your searches based off the outcome of `SEARCH("save=",A1)` or change the second search function to be  `SEARCH(")(name=",A1)`.